QGIS IDW interpolation does not show the list of attributes
I am trying to use a point layer as the input layer for IDW to generate an interpolated map.
The Table Attribute of the corresponding shapefile looks:

In which I used "field_4" and "field_3" values for the x and y of the point locations.
I want however to interpolate based on attribute "field_5". The issue is that when I try to read this vector layer as the input of the IDW interface non of attributes (except x and y) are available:

I think it should certainly be related to the way that I built this shapefile (using python and geopandas library) that makes the attribute data-types unsuitable for this procedure.
Indeed when I check the corresponding "type" for each attribute in properties->Information, all of them are represented as "String" type which is strange!


You are right @Bera, I had to precise my question. The issue is solved now by using QGIS functions. But I have to investigate further how to fix the issue at the time of creation of shapefile with functions of geopandas.

Try .astype

As you already know your "field_5" is of type sting while you need a numeric field for IDW interpolation.
The simplest way to get a numeric field for your IDW interpolation is to create a new numeric field with the Field Calculator.
You may create a virtual field (virtual field are not part of the data so you are not modifying your original shapefile : they only exist in the specific project where you define them. Note that they are calculated on the fly and are auto-updating (with complex operation and/or large number of row this could slow down your project)) or a add a permanent new field to your shapefile.
for that :

At the top of your attribute table click the abacus icon to open the
field calculator
Made sure that the "Create a new field" (and "Create virtual field" if you want a virtual field)
check boxes are checked
Give a name to the (virtual) field to be created (in the below exemple
"IDW_FIELD") and choose a suitable numeric field type like decimal
Input this formula to convert from string to real :
to_real("field_5") and click OK

After that the new field should be available in the IDW tool "Interpolation attribute" dropdown (note that, as commented by @Spacedman, if there are any actual text value on your original field they will appear as Null after converting...)


Might be worth pointing out here that if any of the string values can't be interpreted as numbers then you'll get a NULL value or similar. Its possible the reason these are strings is because there are some non-numeric values in there.
